# How can i set scope of facebook login URL for php, If I dont want to let user change "edit info he provide"?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

[image]

I want to remove option for user to edit info he provide
I need email address of user any how
Let me know how can i freeze that scope?

[image]

I want this type of view
how its possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t change that behaviour, you can only check for the email after the user authorized your App.

Or you can check if the user accepted a specific permission after authorization with this endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/permissions

Another way is to set "return_scopes" in the login process:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
}, {
   scope: 'publish_actions', 
   return_scopes: true
});
```

> By setting the return_scopes option to true in the option object when calling FB.login, you will receive a list of the granted permissions in the grantedScopes field on the authResponse object.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1

The second screen may be from an older App created before end of April 2014 (v1.0).

Comment: see my second screenshot

Comment: may be an older app created before end of april 2014. i have edited my answer to include more possibilities.

Comment: i am using php sdk, if i am writing
scope: 'publish_actions', 
   return_scopes: true
its not working as you said

Comment: the php sdk does not offer the return_scopes parameter afaik. but i suggest using the javascript sdk for login anyway, it´s much easier to handle and the recommended way.